# How do I fix Bad state: field does not exist within the DocumentSnapshotPlatform. I keep getting this error

Tags: firebase

I have problem getting data from firebase to my flutter app and I get an error with regards to the two fields below.
'final messageText = message['text'];
final messageSender = message['message'];'

Code below:

```
StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
          stream: _firestore.collection('messages').snapshots(),
          builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
            final messages = snapshot.data!.docs;
            print(messages);
            List<Text> messageWidgets = [];
            for (var message in messages) {
              final messageText = message['text'];
              final messageSender = message['message'];

              final messageWidget =
                  Text('$messageText from $messageSender');
              messageWidgets.add(messageWidget);
            }
            return Column(
              children: messageWidgets,
            );
          },
        ),
```

Answer (score 0):

You are iterating the docs of the query, and then trying to access the data of the document directly. A document in Firestore has different metadata assigned to it, like the `uid` of the document. The fields you add to a document in firestore is not metadata, but the actual data. If you want to access this, you first need to get the data from the document using the `data()` method.

Your updated code should therefore look like this.

```dart
StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
          stream: _firestore.collection('messages').snapshots(),
          builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
            final messages = snapshot.data!.docs;
            print(messages);
            List<Text> messageWidgets = [];
            for (var doc in messages) {
              final message = doc.data() as Map<String, dynamic>; // <-- Notice this
              final messageText = message['text'];
              final messageSender = message['message'];

              final messageWidget =
                  Text('$messageText from $messageSender');
              messageWidgets.add(messageWidget);
            }
            return Column(
              children: messageWidgets,
            );
          },
        ),
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, however now I get 'The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'Object''. The ['text'] and ['message'] part is red underlined in android studio

Comment: Updated the answer now @Qube. My bad, I forgot to cast.